# BrainTree - DropUI - Choose Payment Method

Tags: ios, swift2, braintree, payment-method

Looking at the Braintree vault, I have 1 customer with 2 payment methods.

How can I get the screen with the payment method selection to appear? I am using the BrainTree DropIn with the iOS SDK (Swift 2.0), but I don't mind tips on any platform. I can get the DropIn to enter a card and pay, but not the payment method selection screen.

Any help?

Many thanks,
Polis

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't enough information here to provide much assistance. I assume you've walked through [the iOS setup guide](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/ios/v4) and other [iOS SDK documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/ios/v4). If you have, I would recommend including code snippets and [contacting Braintree Support](https://support.braintreepayments.com) if you have a specific problem with your integration.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: Yes, you will need to add support in your server side of things to look up the client id and generate a token based on that rather than a randomized one. No changes in your client side assuming you already pass a client id. Let me know if you need to see some code. I know the BT documentation can be very sparse with the details, took me a while to figure it out.